# Rails 4 - Processing card payments when there is a form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm processing card payments on an ecommerce/marketplace app. Users fill out an order form with shipping address, billing info, etc. and submit. If the form is filled with no errors, the form works as intended i.e. the order is saved and card is charged.

Problem: When the form has an error (example: zip is blank), the form page returns an error message. But if the credit card info is correct, the user gets charged. I need the card to be charged only when there are no form errors.

Here is my `create` method in my order controller. I thought about moving the stripe charge block inside the respond_to block but that wouldn't work because the order should be saved only after the payment is approved.

Since this is a marketplace, I have a payment transfer block below as well i.e. part of the payment is transferred to the seller of the item. This code should run only after payment is processed and order is saved.

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
    token = params[:stripeToken]


    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => token,
        :description => "Charge from ABC"
        )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to thankyou_path(:id => @order.id) }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
        AutoNotifier.orderconf_email(current_user, @order).deliver 
        AutoNotifier.sellerconf_email(current_user, @seller, @order).deliver 
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end #end respond_to

     if !@seller.recipient.blank?
      transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create(
          :amount => (((@listing.price * 97.1) - 30) * 0.8).floor, #converting to cents per stripe requirement. 80 percent in cents goes to seller.
          :currency => "usd",
          :recipient => @seller.recipient
          )
    end #end transfer

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:danger] = e.message
    end #end rescue

  end #end begin

end #end create
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, I used a variation of the solution posted below by Deep. Sorry for the delayed response. i'm not here much.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is move the stripe charge into a method in model. And then just add a condition like this:

```
def save_with_payment
    if self.valid?
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
    :currency => "usd",
    :card => token,
    :description => "Charge from ABC"
    )
      self.stripe_customer_token = charge.id
      save!
    else
      logger.error "#{self.errors.inspect}"
      false
    end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating charge: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
```

And in controller you can do is:

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save_with_payment
        format.html { redirect_to thankyou_path(:id => @order.id) }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
        AutoNotifier.orderconf_email(current_user, @order).deliver 
        AutoNotifier.sellerconf_email(current_user, @seller, @order).deliver 
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end #end respond_to
```

So this will check if the data entered by user is valid then only it will charge the user. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're creating the charge before you create the order because you want to make sure the transaction works before you create the order.

You have a few options here.

1. You can validate the order with `@order.valid?` before you create the charge, but that will return false if you have validations on the stripe charge.
2. You can also authenticate the charge without capturing it, as per [this page on the stripe support website](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture), like so:

   ```
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
       :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
       :currency => "usd",
       :card => token,
       :description => "Charge from ABC"
       :capture => false
       )
   ```

   Notice the `:capture => false`. Then once you create the order, you can call `charge.capture`. But you'll still want to handle the (unlikely) case where `charge.capture` returns an error or raises an exception, and delete the order.

You can also refund the payment if `@order.save` returns false, but I'd recommend at least checking for input errors before you capture the charge.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look into transactions. If something in the transaction raises an exception, everything in it will be reverted.